# Observe LiveData from LifeCycleService

Tags: android, service, android-lifecycle, lifecycle, android-livedata

I'm using the google android architecture component and I have a foreground service which is a LifeCycleService.

The problem is when i try to observe a LiveData from my repository, the observable onChanged doesn't trigger. If I use observeForever instead of observe it does trigger.

What could cause such a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I was overriding the onBind without calling super.onBind which didn't trigger the LifeCycleService to be in a STARTED state. Which meant that my observer was always inactive

Comment: this was the issue for me, because normal Service implementation doesn't need super.onBind, but changing it to LifeCycleService needs it and is easy to miss! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who's using `repeatOnLifecycle()` to observe a flow inside a LifecycleService, be sure to use `Lifecycle.State.STARTED`. Using resumed like we do for activities or fragments will never trigger flow collection.