# LifecycleService : bind or not to bind

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am observing some data inside my LifecycleService like so

```
 bkMediaManager.isReady.observe(this, {
            Util.log("live data value $it")
            if(it){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(context, "Buffering", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
```

but it is not triggered if I do not pass super.onBind
like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50932201/observe-livedata-from-lifecycleservice) says.
So I did and it worked but now I cannot bind with the service without returning my Binder instance to call the methods inside it like I did before with normal services. How do I communicate with services now ?

Comment: show the code where you do bind and call methods

Comment: override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {

        return mBinder
    }

Comment: the service does not work unless I return super.onBind(intent)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```kotlin
override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
    super.onBind(intent)
    return mBinder
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.